# Duplicate file exception in androidstudio HTTPCore version.properties

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

have project in android studio and i am using several dependencies in that project my gradle file looks like this

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.omgproductionsinc.panicsosplus"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
//compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(':FacebookSDK')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.3.5.jar')
compile (files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar'))/*{
            exclude "org/apache/http/version.properties"
 }*/
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/splunk-mint-4.0.7.jar')
compile (files('libs/twitpic4j.jar'))
compile files(('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar'))
compile files(('libs/sendgrid-0.1.2-jar.jar'))
//compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
compile ('oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2')
compile ('oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
//compile 'org.lucee:httpcomponents-httpcore:4.4.4'

}
```

I am getting exception like

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK org/apache/http/version.properties
Error:com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK org/apache/http/version.properties
Error:com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK org/apache/http/version.properties
```

I have surfed through many questions but none of the solution worked for me please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: call `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'`

Comment: or `compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5'`

Comment: tried your both options but it gives error of Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method execute(Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest;)Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/CloseableHttpResponse; in class Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya 
   
 
tried your both options but it gives error of Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method execute(Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest;)Lorg‌​/apache/http/client/‌​methods/CloseableHtt‌​pResponse; in class Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)

Comment: add `android {
    compileSdkVersion //your
    buildToolsVersion //your
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }`

Comment: add `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yes, its his issue So please help him

Comment: if above trick not works then roll back previous and add `packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }`

Comment: worked thank you @Intellij Amiya

Answer (score 2):

You are getting

> Error:com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
>   copied in APK org/apache/http/version.properties
>   Error:com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate
>   files copied in APK org/apache/http/version.properties

You should enable **[packagingOptions](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html)**

```
 packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```

and set `multiDexEnabled true`
Then **Clean-Rebuild** Your Project and **RUN** .